# Cursor or database not closed error

Tags: android, sqlite

i have made a few multi activity database applications using sqlite,
but i get error messages in logcat like

> Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed
>   or database not closed error

my apps seems to run fine.
i tried to close cursor and database using the onDestroy or after query or on changing activity,
but then either the application crashes or i get null pointer exception or an empty listview.

i would like to know what problems i can face if i just leave things as it is,
like database corruption or interfrence with other applications.

also i want to know if suppose i declare cursor

```
protected Cursor a_cursor;
```

in 1st activity, do i need to use the same declaration in the next activity 
or do i need to use

```
protected Cursor b_cursor;
```

similarly for DbHelper,Context,Sqlitedatabase etc in 1st activity like

```
 private SQLiteDatabase adb;
 private DatabaseHelper aDbHelper;
    private final Context aCtx;
```

to

```
 private SQLiteDatabase bdb;
 private DatabaseHelper bDbHelper;
    private final Context bCtx;
```

in 2nd activity

the structure of the program is like this

DatabaseHelper -- to create some tables or upgrade

DbAdapter -- to insert or update tables

Activity1 -- search a table and listview  -- on list itemclick  --Activity2 ,
context menu to add some details to 2nd table

Activity2 -- item details  and button for Activity3

Activity3 -- Edit item  -- return

Activity4 -- 2nd table listview

Activity5 -- Database import export

sorry if my question seems too ametuerish or primitive
but i am not a programmer and the apps are for my personal use 
not intended for the market

actually i did not find a complete example to suit my needs 
so i just added bits and peices from many examples to get things done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be that we'd say to use [managedQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) to deal with this stuff. But since the [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) was added, I suggest using that to keep everything straight. The cursor loader wasn't added until API Level-10, but you can still use it on lesser API levels through the [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

For an example of using a CursorLoader, you can checkout this [Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html#example) (or the corresponding [full-fledged example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderCursor.html).)

Comment: if im not mistaken managedQuery is already deprecated in api level 10. used it in a previous project, had too many memObj/cursor issues because of it. yes, use loaders.

Comment: Yes, that why I said  "we used to use it" and why I said he should use a CursorLoader instead.

Comment: Thanks Kurtis for your reply. i am on API 8 ,so i can use managedQuery Do you have a snippet or example of managedQuery

Comment: i have yet to find any solution to this ridiculous error. as far as I'm concerned, I'm closing everything, but Android differs.  I'm just going to build everything post API 10 for the CursorLoader.

Comment: Also any comments on database corruption issue and declaration of cursor

Comment: Wolly, remmember, you can still use CursorLoader even if you on API 8 through the Support Package. That I know has examples.

Comment: hi Kurtis ,i would like to use the CursorLoader. Can you link me to some examples

Comment: for some reason the SupportPackage fails to show in SDK AVD Manager. let me resolve that. i am using linux and eclipse3.5.1 and have API8 and API7 installed

Comment: not yet,just got the support package install.thanks kurtis for your help.i'll need a few days to get a grasp of this CursorLoader.can you comment something on the database corruption and the declaration issue ?

Comment: using CursorLoader seems too complex for me at the moment and might need a redesign of the entire app,isnt there a simpler solution?

Comment: yea, use managedQuery. It's deprecated but you can still use it.

Comment: CursorLoader wasnt as difficult as anticipated.Thanks Kurtis for your help.all working now.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! Yea, the Loaders are actually suuuuuuuper nice. They're my new favorite class.

Answer (score 0):

when populating your cursor, try doing it this way

```
Cursor c;
try {
   c = managedQuery...
   lv.setAdapter(c);
} catch(...) {
} finally {
   if(null!=c)
   c.close()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josephus , i,ll try this and post the result

Comment: i think managedQuery only works with content providers,so i might not be using this